# looping over object constructors

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, javascript-objects

I have a constructor:

```
function Library(author, readingStatus) {
  this.author = author;
  this.readerStatus = readingStatus;
}
```

And I create objects with it

```
var One = new Library("One", true);
var Two = new Library("Two", false);
```

I want to loop over each object, and then within an if/else statement, I want to check if `readingStatus` is `true`. If yes, I want to alert something like "already read".

I have tried different ways but it doesn't work. Could anyone show how?
**EDIT** this is what I have tried.

```
for (var i = 0; i < Library.length; i++) {
var book = "'" + Library[i].title + "'" + ' by ' + Library[i].author + ".";
if (Library[i].readingStatus) {
  window.alert("Already read " + book);
} else
{
 window.alert("You still need to read " + book);
}
}
```

Comment: using `if` condition inside your constructor?

Comment: yes.I want to loop over to see if readingStatus is true.

Comment: so, what's the problem? `if(this.readerStatus){...}`

Comment: You can simply use if else condition inside your constructor and do not required to use a loop.

Comment: I've edited for more information.

Comment: I have used if else without a loop as well.it didnt work. @BhojendraNepal

Answer (score 1):

`Library` is not an item on which you can iterate. To loop over the objects, it is better to create an array of objects. For example, you've two objects here, `One` and `Two`. So you can create an array of them, like this:

```
var array = [One, Two];
```

Now you can loop through them and check the desired condition like this:

```
array.forEach(item => {
  if (item.readerStatus === true) {
    alert('already read');
  }
});
```

Here is a complete example, in action:

```js
function Library(author, readingStatus) {
  this.author = author;
  this.readerStatus = readingStatus;
}

var One = new Library("One", true);
var Two = new Library("Two", false);
var array = [One, Two];

array.forEach(item => {
  if (item.readerStatus === true) {
    alert(item.author + ' already read');
  }
});
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be better writing only : if (item.readingStatus){ To make it shorter?

Comment: @lux -- That will make it shorter, but I wanted to strictly check for boolean values. `item.readingStatus` will be true for `'a'` or for `[]`, and for all the [truthy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).